# How to use the app.manifest file of a library instead of the calling project

Tags: c#, .net, com, manifest

I have the following code:

```
    public static void Init()
    {
        Type myClassAdapterType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DotNetAdapter.Adapter");
        object myClassAdapterInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClassAdapterType);
        IAdapter myClassAdapter = (IAdapter)myClassAdapterInstance;
        DWAdapter = myClassAdapter;
    }
```

This Methode is part of a Library which helps me access a .NET 4 Library through COM interop in a .NET 2 Library.

I based it on this Tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/204406/How-To-Use-a-NET-Based-DLL-From-NET-Based-Appl

The Code can be viewed here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-a-NET-4-Based-DLL-bb141db3

In his example you can see how a console application accesses a .Net 4 Library through COM interop using the app.manifest to operate registration free.
In my Version I replaced the Console Application by a .NET 2.0 Library.

To test the Library I simply created an Init-methode which is beeing called by a .net 2.0 console application. The console application has no app.manifest file, the library does.

**My Problem** is that the first line returns a null. So `myClassAdapterType` is null because `Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DotNetAdapter.Adapter")` returns null.

That line should be able to retrieve the Type by accessing the app.manifest file. But herein lies the problem. Instead off reading the manifest of the library which contains the method, it appears that VS trys to read the (non existant) manifest file of the calling console application.

**(TLDR) My Question:** 
Is there a way to either change `Type myClassAdapterType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DotNetAdapter.Adapter");` so that it accesses the library's app.manifest. Or is there a way to tell VS to use the app.manifest in folder x?

PS: IF I add the manifest off the library to the calling console application it works but I am not allowed to use a manifest file here.

Comment: You are getting this pretty fundamentally wrong.  The manifest is required to find the DLL.  Putting the manifest in the DLL gives Windows a chicken-and-egg problem, it can't find the DLL so it can't find the manifest either.  It **must** be included in the console mode app.  If you are "not allowed" to do that then you of course have no use for a manifest at all.

Comment: Currently it works like this:

Comment: Currently it works like this:
I have a DotNet2ConsoleApp which uses the DotNet2Library by normally refrencing it. The DotNet2Library needs a DotNet4Library to work. To accomplish this The DotNet2Library uses the app.manifest to define the dependency on the DotNet4Library. That is why the DotNet2Library uses a app.manifest file.

The DotNet2ConsoleApp does not need a app.manifest because the DotNet2Library is normally refrenced within the project of the DotNet2ConsoleApp.

I am a beginner so I might actually be doing it fundamentally wrong. If so please explain and thank you for your reply!

Comment: That's not a manifest, you are talking about the app.exe.config configuration file that's used to configure the CLR.  Yes, doesn't work since the CLR looks in the directory where the EXE file is stored.  If you are not allowed to copy files in that directory then you must register the DLLs in the GAC.  Always the proper solution for [ComVisible] code to avoid DLL Hell anyway.

Comment: I don't undesrstand how it is not a manifest if I added them through VS by Add > Application Manifest.
I can't use the registry, which is why I use the approach with manifests.
If you have the time, please look at the second link in my original Post, it includes the source code of the example and allows more insight. All I want to do is replace the Net2Assembly which is a ConsoleApplication with a .Net 2.0 Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got an answer from a colleague which I'd like to share in case somebody makes the same mistake I made.

The answer is that it is actually not possible to use a manifest in a Library. What confused me, was that the Adapter-Library which is used to comunicate over COM interop is a Library which has a manifest that is beeing used. What I didn't know is that this is donw because of the use of COM. The Library is being hosted and the manifest is used. 
Without that the manifest is part of the Library-Project but is not beeing used.

I don't know if I explained this correctly but I hope it helps.